# Почему аудио поток не воспроизводится?

Tags: php, javascript, web-audio

Есть поток **http://maxkondaurov.ru:7777/**  (там уже все настроено идет трансляция с удаленного ноута и плеера  )

Для начала я хочу понять почему сам поток не вопсроизводится через простой тег аудио ?

```html
<audio src="http://maxkondaurov.ru:7777/" controls autobuffer> </audio>
```

вместо этого скачивается файл .pls , и в плеере уже впринципе все играет. Такой боли не надо бы

Т.е я хочу для начала просто подверстать простую страничку с этим потоком, возможно прикрутить какие то плееры для визуальных эффектов и прочее.

В дальнейшем стоит задача создать полноценное радио с мета инфой , чтоб тянулись названия миксов, картинки и т.д кучу всего нагуглил вижу , нужно по сути шизамить в реалтайме и подсовывать инфу, вот такую штуку нашел [Апи какое то](https://www.acrcloud.com/ru/)
Как думаете стоит в нем дальше копаться? или использовать что то другое? Только не предлагайте всякие радиоцмс, это совсем дно)

Comment: Смущает то, что ссылка на сам поток и web страницу один и тот же. Возможно, на стороне сервера разбираются заголовки для выдачи верного ответа клиенту. Возможно, из-за браузера вместо потока отдается html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался, надо было уточнить что на сервере стоит shoutcast , а для него надо вот так писать поток 
http://maxkondaurov.ru:7777/;stream.nsv